# Process starts a new CMD instance

Tags: c#, cmd, process, instance, netsh

I have a command line application that calls a 'netsh' process and changes some IP information. The problem that I have is that every time I call my app in CMD or PowerShell, it starts a new instance of CMD(opens a new CMD window and closes it after it's finished executing)

I would like to know if there is a way to have everything happen in the same window

here is the code that starts a process:

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", queryStr);
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();

Console.WriteLine("netsh query string is: " + "***" + queryStr + "***");
```

This is my first question, please don't judge too harshly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. You could hide the Shell, while redirecting the ouput. For example,

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", queryStr);
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();

var output =  p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

[ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle?view=netframework-4.8) allows to set the state of Window when the process starts. In the current scenario, you could set it to `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`

[ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.8) indicates whether to use the OS's Shell. Disabling this would help in redirecting the output.

[ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=netframework-4.8) indicates whether the output is written to `StandardOutput`. By setting it to true, you can redirect the output stream and use the `Process.StandardOutput` to read the output and display as per application design